# Linking elements in one array to elements in another array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, variables, nsuserdefaults

I have a UITableViewController. Each row is populated from a global array. 
This global array Describes the title of a task. Each task should have 3 associated variables which are strings.

I want to be able to click on the title of task in the table view controller and have the associated variables linked to that title.
The global array will be grow and shrink as the end user appends or removes titles from the global array.

I am not sure of the best way to do this, any suggestions?

Note: the global array is populated in from another separate viewController.swift file. I wish to assign the variable in another viewController.swift as well, hence I made these variables global. However I am not sure how I can assign different variable values depending on the title selected in the table view.

```
import UIKit

var Programs: [String] = []

var Variable1: [String] = []
var Variable2: [String] = []
var Variable3: [String] = []

class ProgramList: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

@IBOutlet weak var programTableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    load()
}


override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    programTableView.reloadData()
    save()
}

//saving current state of programs array
func save(){
    UserDefaults.standard.set(Programs, forKey: "notes")
}

//loading saved program array
func load() {
    if let loadedData: [String] = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "notes") as? [String] {
        Programs = loadedData
        programTableView.reloadData()
    }
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Programs.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell
    cell.programTitle.text = Programs[indexPath.row]
    return cell
}

//Removing Item by swipping left & saving this newly established array
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if editingStyle == UITableViewCell.EditingStyle.delete {
        Programs.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        programTableView.reloadData()
        save()
    }

 }
}
```

Comment: Think object-oriented. Use a custom struct which contains all properties of one task rather than multiple arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```
struct Item {
  let title:String
  let others:[String]
}
```

or

```
struct Item {
  let title,v1,v2,v3:String 
}
```

instead of separate arrays , then

```
var programs = [Item]()
```

Comment: Using this when I would go to set the "cell.programTitle.text = Programs[indexPath.row]" this would not work as it is not of type string? its of type item.

Comment: should be `cell.programTitle.text = Programs[indexPath.row].title`

Comment: how would it then be possible  in the load function to get make  'Programs = loadedData' work as it wouldn't be able to assign value of type '[String]' to type '[Item]'

Comment: please add a separate question for this , post link here for specific help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59381757/resolving-conflicting-struct-value-types-in-swift